# Flushing out Message queues in Linux systems

Tags: linux, message-queue, flush

I am working on my codebase where I need to flush out the existing messages in my message queue .I would preferably not like to delete the message queue and create it again.(But thats like the worst case option).Can someone guide me in this regard?
Thanks 
Satwik

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not the smartest solution, but a naïve approach could be to write a dumb client application that consumes all the messages inside the given queue in order to empty it.